# Flutter - How to add hot reload on save with nano editor?

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, terminal, nano

My 8 gig ram machine can't handle a VM and building  a flutter project simultaneously in vscode. So I've decided to go with nano editor. It does the job, but everytime I want hot reload, I have to manually go to the terminal where I'm running flutter run and hit r there. Is there a way to set hot reload on save like that of vscode?

Comment: If I could, I would :)  I don't have a physical device atm.

Comment: not really, the usable amount of ram seems to be only 6800 mb's. And it uses swap memory pretty much all the time, I can get my work done with that, but I can't concentrate on the project if I have to wait for a letter to appear on the screen after I've typed it.

Comment: I think mine is the 'official' android emulator(comes with android studio) and it eats a lot of resources. And also, I have to have the resources to run a browser, to quickly search something up. When typing this comment, I have 4600 mb of ram with 6 chrome tabs open. If I have to develop apps with the resources that I currently have, I would have to feed three giants, the VM, vscode, and flutter run which also eats up resources. And after doing all of that, my system will be running any of those three programs in swap memory, and then it will be all but a nice experience for development :)